# Understanding User-Agents when scraping URL data using JSoup

Tags: jsoup, user-agent

My basic goal is to create something like a typical web-unfurl project for web links. For that, I am using JSoup.

For the User-Agent, I was initially using the string -

`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; de-de) AppleWebKit/523.10.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Safari/523.10`

for the following method call -

```
public void connect(String URL) throws IOException {
    Document document = Jsoup
        .connect(URL)
        .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
        .referrer(REFERRER)
        .timeout(12000)
        .followRedirects(true)
        .get();
  }
```

But, I could see that the URL wasn't being 'correctly' scraped when using the above-mentioned User-Agent, as opposed to something like just `Mozilla/5.0`. For instance, I wasn't receiving the oEmbed data with the `type=application/json+oembed` meta tag in the `head` of the URL when I was using the former but worked when I used the later. I am guessing that it's probably something to do with the `.js` scrips of the URL being sent with the former User-Agent while it's plain-old HTML for the later, but I am yet to understand it in detail.

I understand that `Mozilla/5.0` is just supposed to be Mozilla-compatible, but what exactly does `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; de-de) AppleWebKit/523.10.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Safari/523.10` mean?

Can someone clarify my questions, or point me to some useful documentation for User-Agents?

Comment: See [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/). You can paste there different strings and analyze them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Web browsers use a User-Agent string value as follows:

```
Mozilla/[version] ([system and browser information]) [platform] ([platform details]) [extensions].
```

For example, Safari on the iPad has used the following:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405
```

The components of this string are as follows:

Mozilla/5.0: Previously used to indicate compatibility with the    Mozilla rendering engine.

(iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X;    en-us): Details of the system in which the browser is running.    AppleWebKit/531.21.10: The platform the browser uses.

(KHTML, like    Gecko): Browser platform details.

Mobile/7B405: This is used by the    browser to indicate specific enhancements that are available directly    in the browser or through third parties. An example of this is    Microsoft Live Meeting which registers an extension so that the Live    Meeting service knows if the software is already installed, which    means it can provide a streamlined experience to joining meetings.

You can read more about User-Agent from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent). There are also links to documentation if you need more specific information.